# Android Dynamic layout base on json response

Tags: android

I want to make a layout based on json response.

below is my json. now i want to  make  with it a layout . in json "type_html" is my type of view i want to create.

```
{
    "file": {
        "@attributes": {
            "id": "form-1",
            "name": "frm1",
            "method": "POST",
            "action": "#"
        },
        "colonne": {
            "@attributes": {
                "id": "f_col_1",
                "width": "700px",
                "height": "178px"
            },
            "element": [
                {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "type_html": "radio",
                        "idco": "1",
                        "idli": "1",
                        "label": "Result",
                        "id": "nb_0",
                        "name": "st",
                        "val_liste": "a=Is Doctor satisfied; b=Is Doctor not satisfied;",
                        "val_defaut": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "type_html": "checkbox",
                        "idco": "1",
                        "idli": "2",
                        "label": "abc",
                        "id": "nb_1",
                        "name": "ch",
                        "val_liste": "a= Is doctor taking interest;",
                        "val_defaut": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "type_html": "radio",
                        "idco": "1",
                        "idli": "3",
                        "label": "Gender",
                        "id": "nb_2",
                        "name": "rb",
                        "val_liste": "a=Male;b=Female;",
                        "val_defaut": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "type_html": "radio",
                        "idco": "1",
                        "idli": "4",
                        "label": "Are you handicaped ?",
                        "id": "nb_3",
                        "name": "nb_3",
                        "val_liste": "a=Yes;b=No;",
                        "val_defaut": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**here is my code which i tired**

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

            JSONObject jObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            JSONObject attribute=jObject.getJSONObject("@attributes");

            Log.d("in for",jObject.toString());

            String htmltype=attribute.getString("type_html");
            String Value=attribute.getString("val_liste");
            String labString=attribute.getString("label");

            DynamicTodo dynamicTodo=new DynamicTodo(htmltype, Value, labString);

            arrayList.add(dynamicTodo);

            Log.d("For html",htmltype);


            viewto.add(htmltype);
            valueto.add(Value);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

              //Log.d("Valee",valueto.get(0));


    for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){

        LinearLayout myLayout = null;
        if((arrayList.get(i).getTypeHtml()).equals("radio")){


            Log.d("Arrra","aaaaaaa");
            String Valliste=arrayList.get(i).getValue();
            String Lable=arrayList.get(i).getLable();


            RadioGroup group=new RadioGroup(DynamicFeedback.this);
             RadioButton Radiobutton=new RadioButton(DynamicFeedback.this);


              Radiobutton.setText(Lable);
              group.addView(Radiobutton);

             myLayout = new LinearLayout(DynamicFeedback.this);
                  myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                  myLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                  LinearLayout.LayoutParams radioParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                  myLayout.addView(group,radioParams);

        }
        if((arrayList.get(i).getTypeHtml()).equals("radio")){
            setContentView(myLayout);
        }

    }
    }


    }
```

it just puting up last view

can anyone answer it....

Comment: Please format your json and mark it as a code, it is impossible to read as of now.

Comment: Soon we will do the work on it broo...Yet now i am not getting you

Comment: you can check out https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus if it satisfies your use case. You can create views from data dynamically by defining the layout in json itself. I will leave it as an answer too.

Answer (score 2):

you can check out [proteus](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus) if it satisfies your use case. You can create views defining the layout in JSON itself.

A sample layout:

```
{
  "type": "LinearLayout",
  "orientation": "vertical",
  "padding": "16dp",
  "children": [{
    "type": "TextView",
    "layout_width": "200dp",
    "gravity": "center",
    "text": "~{{user.profile.name}} ({{user.profile.experience}}$(number))"
  }, {
    "type": "HorizontalProgressBar",
    "layout_width": "200dp",
    "layout_marginTop": "8dp",
    "max": 6000,
    "progress": "$user.profile.experience"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about checkbox selector with proteus?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could directly refer a selector like `"background": "@drawable/selector_checkbox` or you could also create a selector at runtime. `"background": {  ... selector properties ... }`. I urge you to post another question SO for this as answering in a comment is very difficult.

Comment: Thanks, If I use "button":"@drawable/checkbox_selector" it is working fine, but if I use "button":{
        "type":"selector",
        "children":[
          {
            "drawable":"@drawable/check",
            "state_checked":true
          },
          {
            "drawable":"@drawable/uncheck",
            "state_checked":false
          }
        ]
      }  getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: drawable is not a valid state.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Post another question please.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you are creating *myLayout* inside your **for** loop, then adding a view to it. Therefore you are creating a new one each time and the previous one is getting lost. You need to create the layout before the start of the loop, add views to it one at a time inside it, then call setContentView after the loop finishes. Otherwise you will only see the last one you added.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the Example given [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

You will get Concept and Simple understanding on parsing JSON Object and access to the attributes.

Comment: sir thanku but i do not want to know how to parse json but how to make layout based on that json